# Xfce, where could I change icons (source and dimension) for window buttons?

Tags: icons, xfce

In xfce, where can I change (set path for) icons for `Window buttons` plugin, and change resolution? Quite big now in panel, I want them smallest, same as in `Notification area` (2 last icons on the righ side).

[image]

How exactly icon works in xfce `4.12`? Is it better in version `4.14`?

Thanks.

Comment: Window button icon size adopt with the height of the panel, but that may be hard coded in the plugin. Thus, it may not be possible to tweak the size. Try resizing the panel first.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, when panel is resized, icons are resized too, but I don't want resize panel, just icons. Another way to do it is modify/scale picture in icon with same layout resolution in gimp, but how can I set path for new icons in `window buttons`? In `~/.local/share/icons/myicons`, and then `index.theme`? Is any configuration file to set path for all icons in system?